# Angular2 - recursive html without making a new component?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

In angular 1 I was able to do something like:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="commentView.html">
    <div>
        <div style="float: left; position: absolute;" ng-style="comment.displayPercent">
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="commentReplies.html">
    <div>
        <div class="commentChildBoxStyle" ng-hide="comment.hideComment">
            <div style="min-width: 250px;">

                <div ng-repeat="comment in comment.replies" ng-include="'commentReplies.html'"></div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

I realize I can recursively call a component along with it's template in Angular2, but is there a way to recursively build HTML only?  The logic seems like it would fit better with the parent component rather than with a series of child components.

Comment: Search for `ngTemplateOutlet`

Answer (score 24):

There certainly is a `html` only solution in Angular:

```
<h1>Angular 2 Recursive List</h1>
<ul>
  <ng-template #recursiveList let-list>
    <li *ngFor="let item of list">
      {{item.title}}
      <ul *ngIf="item.children.length > 0">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:{ $implicit: item.children }"></ng-container>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:{ $implicit: list }"></ng-container>
</ul>
```

Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/arniebradfo/5cf89c362cc216df6fc1d9ca4d536b72).